# php-fpm create new session every time

Tags: session, nginx, php

I am using php-fpm for nginx. At first, everything is fine, after sometime each refresh create new session. Interesting is at the beginning the value of 
**session.use_cookies** is **On**, suddenly it changes to **Off**. 
There is no log error, nothing. Once I restart php-fpm service, it would be fine for some time but again same problem afterwards. 
would be great if someone has idea.